# How to implement fanny (soft clustering) for a large Dataset?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to implement soft clustering on a imbalanced Dataset. The dataset has around 200k rows and 40 columns. 
Whenever i run the `fanny()` function, RStudio crashes and I am forced to start a new session.

I can run the `cmeans()` successfully on the above dataset, but when i used the the `fanny()` function.
It initially used to show this error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 123.5 Gb

So i added `--max-vsize=1500000M` in the target(Properties) while launching R. After adding this the RAM usage would hit 31.8 GB whenever I ran the `fanny()` function. And after a couple of minutes the RStudio would crash.

```r
library(cluster)
#The dataset 'train' has around 20 factor columns and 20 integer columns with 200k rows.
Cluster <- fanny(trainSet, 3)
```

Comment: How can an unsupervised data set be "imbalanced"? That is a term from supervised classification.

Comment: The target variable is present in the actual dataset, but i am trying to run clustering on the same data after removing the target variable.  This is only for increasing my understanding about the data.

Comment: Well, wouldn't it give you more understanding if it discovered clusters within the big class?

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention it. I am running clustering only on majority class, which is like 90% for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently fanny tries to use a distance matrix.

Hence I suggest that you carefully study the ideas of the algorithm and whether it *needs* that matrix, or whether it can be efficiently implemented (that means to write the algorithm, not just to call it!) without doing this. If it needs the distance matrix, then you won't be able to implement fanny on data sets much larger than 65k.